# Jupyter notebook got stuck because of infinite loop

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I don't know if this is the right place for this issue.

I have a scenario where my Jupyter notebook contains a piece of code, suppose something like this:

```
while True:
    pass
```

Basically an infinite loop, accidentally I executed it and the notebook got stuck and not starting. Whenever I reload the page it executes all the cell including the one with infinite loop.

Is there any way I can remove that piece of code and restore my notebook ?

Comment: Uh, Jupyter notebooks shouldn't automatically execute cells... are you *pressing* Run All?

Comment: have you tried Kernel - Interrupt? It will stop your current execution, then you can remove the troubled piece of code and run it again :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it's executing all the cells by default, and I tried interrupting kernel the browser stucks and I cannot edit anything.

Comment: Oh, you mean you are simply hitting *reload* on your *browser*, yeah, that doesn't stop anything. You need to kill the kernel. Probably just open your terminal and kill the jupyter process

Comment: I tried from the command line, and when opened the notebook again in browser it executed all cells again ;) crazy issue. Although other notebooks works fine.

Comment: After shutting everything down (including command prompt window) and starting again, how do you know it's executing all cells?  Are you judging from the star next to the cell number?  Is the kernel busy (gray dot in the top right corner)?

Comment: yes, it was executing the cells while loading in browser. I could see the gray dot. I did resolved it anyway thanks @pylang

Comment: Good to hear. Consider posting an answer an accepting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by interrupting the kernel in command line and later restarting the kernel.

I opened the link in my **default** browser, instead of chrome which I was using.

Removed the snippet which was causing the error, saved to create a checkpoint and reloading the updated book in chrome browser.

Thanks all for the help.