# How to solve Jupyter notebook infinite loop problem

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, infinite-loop

I am new to python and using Jupyter notebook on anaconda prompt. So I ran a program which has a while True loop and it initiated an infinite loop which wont stop. It got my whole laptop hanged and I've to forced shutdown. Now whenever I try to click to open my notebook same problem happens again. How to solve this problem?

It wont let me to shutdown the kernel or anything as my laptop stops responding.

Comment: Open the notebook in something like notepad and delete the offending section.

Comment: Are you saying this is happening after resetting your laptop? I don't see how that's possible, once you've shut down the jupyter server, and restarted it, you kernel will have restarted as well. Then just don't run your infinite loop cell again.   

You should also be able to resolve the infinite loop without crashing your computer by going to the terminal where you are running the jupyter server and hitting ctrl+c

Comment: Jupyter never shuts down kernels unless you do it, or rather turns them back on on boot. Their offending kernel is still up when rebooting jupyter and does not let them shut it down because PC then hangs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter notebook got stuck because of infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495674/jupyter-notebook-got-stuck-because-of-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Go and find the notebook and delete it, it should be located in `C:\Users\UserName` if you are on windows. It should be a .ipynb file.

How are you launching your anaconda + jupyter?

Are you doing `conda activate envname`, followed by `jupyter notebook`?

If you want to keep the notebook, edit it using a text editor like notepad and delete the section with the while loop. It should be written in html so you need to ctrl + f `while` and fine the right line to delete.

But when you start a jupyter notebook, it should not automatically run everytime. There might be something else going on, are you double clicking a .py file directly? If so you should not be doing that, you should be opening jupyter notebook first then finding the file from there.

Double-clicking it might be launching the program, you need to right click and edit, or open the editing program and find it.